# conflict between ksoap2 and actionbarscherlock using Proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I experienced some problem trying to obfuscate my  app code using Proguard tool.
It seems that a conflict occur using both ksoap2 and actionbarsherlock in the same project.

To narrow down the debug opeartions I created a very simple Android project where I used these two libs.
Well if I use only actionbarsherlok I can succesfully exported my app. Same thing if I use only ksoap2 but adding in the proguard-project.txt the following lines:

```
 ignorewarnings
-keep class org.kobjects.** { *; }
-keep class org.ksoap2.** { *; }
-keep class org.kxml2.** { *; }
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

By adding these lines I avoid Proguard generates a bunch of warnings about org.xmlpull class.

When then I try to use both libs leaving the above lines in the proguard-project.txt I get:

```
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Warning: there were 20 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2013-07-31 10:47:46 - testproguard] Error: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
```

I seems the lines in the proguard-project.txt don't work anymore.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```